# Loop through a list of Worksheets and copy paste data into summary sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hello guys I am trying to loop through a list of specific worksheets that are named in a certain range and then copy paste data from those sheets into a summary sheet.

So far I have this code:

```
Sub MacroToDoTheWork()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ZeileUntersucht As Integer
Dim ZeileEintragen As Integer
Dim sheet_name As Range


ZeileUntersucht = 17  
ZeileEintragen = 2

For each sheet_name in Sheets("Frontend").Range("L21:L49")

 For ZeileUntersucht = 20 To 515
    If ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 238).Value = "yes" Then
        Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 1) = ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 1)
        ZeileEintragen = ZeileEintragen + 1

    End If
Next ZeileUntersucht

Next sheet_name

End Sub
```

The For loop is working and goes through the selected sheets range to check for a criteria and pastes the values into another sheet. What I am having issues with is the For each loop. Getting this loop to work for a list of worksheets. The Frontend Range L21:L49 is the range where the worksheet names are stored.

If you need further information, please ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all your sheet names from the `Range` to `sheet_names` array.

Later, when looping through all `Sheets` in `ThisWorkbook`, you can check if current sheet in the loop matches one of the names in the array using the `Match` function.

**Note**: if you try to do it the other way, looping through the sheet names in your `Sheets("Frontend").Range("L21:L49")` , and then use that name of the sheet, you can get a run-time error, if the sheet name won;t be found in any of the sheets in your workbook.

***Modified Code***

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim sheet_names As Variant

' getting the sheet names inside an array
sheet_names = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Frontend").Range("L21:L49").Value)

' loop through worksheets
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ' use Macth function to check if current sheet's name matches one of the sheets in your Range
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sht.Name, sheet_names, 0)) Then
        ' do here your copy Paste


    End If

Next Sht
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will test it immediatly

Comment: @Tim any feedbacks ? is it working as you intended ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand you problem exactly, but I suppose it would be fixed, if you try it like this:

```
For Each sheet_name In Sheets("Frontend").Range("L21:L49")
    Set ws = Worksheets(sheet_name.Text)
    For ZeileUntersucht = 20 To 515
        If ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 238).Value = "yes" Then
            Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 1) = ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 1)
            ZeileEintragen = ZeileEintragen + 1
        End If
    Next ZeileUntersucht
Next sheet_name
```

If your idea is that the `sheet_name` is the name of the worksheet, then it should work.

---

Two ideas:

- avoid using `_` in variable names in VBA, some people hate it.
- [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion if I can make my problem more clear. I was not able to create a working loop that loops through a list of worksheets and performs the second For loop in my macro. I will test your solution right now.

Comment: Thank you for your useful tips, I implemented your solution and the macro does run but after a while I get an error saying "Subscript out of range" and the macro also takes a really long time to run Im guessing because of the large amounts of data it has to check. Is there any way to make this run smoother?

Comment: @Tim - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: @Tim - are you sure that all the sheets in `L21:L49` are present in the Workbook? Without spaces or anything? At which sheet you get this error? Is it present in the workbook? Does it have space or anything? Why do I feel like the guys that are writing questions in English textbooks?

Comment: Haha I feel the stress of getting questioned in class for sure.. I solved the issue in the mean time it was as always human error of misspelling. Thank you sir.